# Find last 2 versions in table with timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, ranking

I have a table called recieved in oracle with the following columns:
Name (varchar2)
version (varchar2)
esptime (timestamp)

The table is continuously filled in and the version will be increased after some time.
But there could be like 100 rows with one version and then after a month i could have an additional 1000 rows with a new version and so on.
Now i would like to create a query that will list me the 2 last versions.

I am trying to make it work using the rank over function.
This is what i have so far but it's not showing the last 2 versions:

```
select '''' || version || '''' as version from (
select version, esptime, rank() over (partition by version order by esptime desc)
from (select distinct version,esptime from recieved)
order by esptime desc)
where ROWNUM <3;
```

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . Assuming that versions are ordered in their naming:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*, dense_rank() over (order by version desc) as seqnum
      from received r
     ) r
where seqnum <= 2;
```

If all versions have the same time, you can use `esptime` in the above.  If versions have different times *and* the name can't be used for ordering, then the simplest method is probably:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by min_version_esptime desc, version) as seqnum
      from (select r.*,
                   min(esptime) over (partition by version) as min_version_esptime
            from received r
           ) r
     ) r
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: The esptime is like the input time of the moment now, so it will never be the same. But i tried the second solution you gave. with R.* i get all the version, so i changed the 1ste line to be select distinct r.version and to make sure i increased the seqnum  to <= 3. There i saw that the second line showed a another version that the last 2.

Comment: if it can help the esptime is like 18-NOV-20 11.21.26.368000000 and the version will be something like 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT. 100 inserts later it could be 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: @Cyrus . . . As requested, provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: some sample data: 
Name|version|esptime 
logon|1.0.0-SNAPSNOT|18-NOV-20 15:27:41.123000000
logon|1.0.0-SNAPSNOT|18-NOV-20 15:27:55.345000000
sign|1.0.0--SNAPSHOT|18-NOV-20 15:29:01.453000000
logon|2.0.0-SNAPSOT|19-NOV-20 16:01:34.786000000
sign|2.0.0-SNAPSHOT|19-NOV-20 16:05:23.454000000
logon|3.0.0-SNAPSHOT|20-NOV-20 03:09:01.434000000
sign|3.0.0-SNAPSHOT|20-NOV-20 06:50:20.748000000

this is a very simple sample but in reality it will be hunderds of lines. as you can see as time goes by the version will increase.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it by not  using the rank() over.
And used some regexp to sort only the numbers part in the version column.